# How do I change how bright it is when sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, lighting

When sculpting the lighting is too bright and I can't see how much I am deforming a shape. How do I change how bright it is?

Comment: Try changing the matcap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

do not sculpt in render view.. if not using just change mat caps :) and in material view, u can change the strength of hdri in the same  mat cap window hope it's help